# Normal polynomial (0x04C11DB7) code to generate the reverse CRC output (0xEDB88320)

Tags: reverse, crc32

E.g., the reverse CRC32 for data ='1' = 0x83dcefb7

But I want to use the normal/forward CRC-32 code with polynomial 0x04C11DB7. What step do I need to follow additionally in order to get the same CRC as the reverse polynomial (i.e: 0x83dcefb7)

I tried with bit reversing the input and the final CRC data. But this is not giving the same result.

I also bit reversed 0x83dcefb7 is 0xedf73bc1. But I don't see this entry in the normal/forward CRC table.

Answer (score 2):

There is not just one "normal/forward CRC-32 code with polynomial 0x04C11DB7". I see four in [Greg Cook's catalogue](https://reveng.sourceforge.io/crc-catalogue/all.htm), and you could define many more. So I have no idea what you're starting with.

There is more than one such reflected CRC as well, but I can tell from your CRC of the string `"1"` that what you want to replicate is the CRC-32/ISO-HDLC.

If you happen to be starting with the forward CRC-32/BZIP2, which has the same initial and final values as CRC-32/ISO-HDLC, then what you would need to do is reflect the input bytes, e.g. `"1"` becomes `"\x8c"`, and then reflect the resulting CRC.